# Connecting remotely to Red Hat

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, vnc, remote-desktop

so I've done this tutorials

http://nearlydeaf.com/?p=1122
http://golubev.org/?p=73

also installed minimal version of gnome in Redhat
my firewall is open on port 3389

and then trying to connect using Remmina but I get unable to connect

what am I doing wrong?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 locally and Red Hat 6 for the remote

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should try to look at the firewall it sounds like its a port or something similar.

Comment: it wasn't the firewall at least not the one within the box but the one on top of the whole local network